# Implementing Okta in React Native and get: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access

Tags: react-native, okta

I'm implementing the Okta signin widget with React Native

I get this:

`Failed to load https://dev-827074.oktapreview.com/api/v1/sessions/me: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

After trying to login, I get the following:

`UnsupportedBrowserError {name: "UNSUPPORTED_BROWSER_ERROR", message: "There was an error sending the request - have you enabled CORS?"}`

Answer (score 1):

We've received similar errors from Okta. What we had to do is add the hostname for the server that hosts the webview as a Trusted Origin.

API -> Trusted Origins -> Add Origin

You can add multiple origins, you probably need to add `http://localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `http://localhost:3000/implicit/callback` to your app's Login Redirect URI's in the General Settings of your Okta app

[image: Okta Login Redirect URIs]

Answer (score 0):

The API you have written does not support CORS. CORS or Cross origin resource sharing allows a web app to submit requests to an API belonging to a different domain. This setting should be enabled on the API side.

This is how it works, whenever a request is sent to a different domain, an OPTIONS method is sent to the server. The server responds back with available options for the web app. If the verb is supported, the browser will send the actual request with the appropriate verb or method (For example, GET or POST). If the verb is not supported, you get the above error message.

In short, enable CORS for your API. If it is a Node / Express API it is just a simple cors package you need to add to your project and use.